# Checking if an element is present with WebElement object

Tags: java, selenium

I need to check if an element is present on page in Java Selenium. Unfortunately all of the explanations on searches are doing it with FindElements(By) but I have a structure of passing the WebElement directly to the method as my elements are already sent by PageFactory.

So I have a structure as follows:

```
public static void verifyElementPresentStatus(WebElement targetElement, String elementName) {
    Boolean elementPresent = MISSING PART
    StepLogger.subVerification(elementName + " should be present");
    Assert.assertTrue(
            elementPresent,
            ValidationHelper.getPresentValidation(elementName)
    );
}
```

and call the method like

```
ExpectationHelper.verifyElementPresentStatus(
            Pages.HomePage().homeHeader,
            Pages.HomePageConstants().pageHeaderText
    );
```

Anyone knows a way to do that?

Comment: As I understand correctly, if your PageFactory sent that WebElement and it is != null it means that this element is present

Comment: Do you want to know if a webElement with a given elementName is present within a targetElement?

Comment: Rafal Sokalski unfortunately it doesn't seem to return null for targetElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write a method that accepts a WebElement as an argument and check whether it exists or not in all cases. This is because the only case where you can have a reference to a WebElement object which doesn't exist is if it was previously existed and then later removed from the DOM (a "stale element"). In order to determine if an element exists or not for the first time, you can only do that by accepting a By argument instead if a WebElement. This way you can use findElements and check that count > 0.

Comment: Previously I was using Protractor and TypeScript. It was possible to make such methods with Web Elements which was a big advantage to create a separate file and return element(By.xpath) and use it for all I need. With this I need to create separate @FindBy and By objects for the same element.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) of WebElement interface, all its method calls

> will do a freshness check to ensure that the element
>   reference is still valid. This essentially determines whether or not
>   the element is still attached to the DOM. If this test fails, then an
>   StaleElementReferenceException is thrown, and all future calls to this
>   instance will fail.

Since you receive a webElement without any validation, consider doing a neutral method call (without any side effects) to check element for `StaleElementReferenceException`. For example, you can call `getSize()` method. Your method logic should look then something like this.

```
public static void verifyElementPresentStatus(WebElement targetElement, String elementName) {
  Boolean elementPresent = true;
  try {
    elementPresent = targetElement.getSize();
  } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
    elementPresent = false;
  }
  StepLogger.subVerification(elementName + " should be present");
  Assert.assertTrue(elementPresent, ValidationHelper.getPresentValidation(elementName));
}
```

Comment: Eugene elementName is not actual name of element. It is a string to be written by the tester to show user friendly test logs. 

I want to check the presence of the element with WebElement targetElement . It is on a separate file loaded with the PageFactory.initElements method.

Comment: @Ceyhun, I have had another idea that might help you, please see the edited asnwer.